# Deep cloning of feature attributes in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I need to make a clone of a feature in OpenLayers (I am using latest 6.3.1 version, but my question is not version specific, I guess).

The feature itself has a method [`.clone()`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Feature-Feature.html#clone). Unfortunately, my attributes/properties defined for feature are objects and arrays and `.clone` method does only shallow copy of the feature. So if I change some value in the cloned object, the original object is changed too.

So, how to make a deep copy of a feature in OpenLayers?

Comment: Can you use getProperties and clone this object deeply by lodash (for instance) and then create new Feature (or evene clone an old one) and pass the cloned object to the setProperties meothdo of the new Feature?

Comment: Thanks, I will try it tomorrow and report the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Anatoly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1376618/anatoly) suggested in comments, it can be done by [`.setProperties()`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Feature-Feature.html#setProperties) method.

EDIT 18.4.2020: As geometry of the feature is included in `.getProperties()` and it cannot be copied properly with `JSON.parse()`/`JSON.stringify()`, I had to add one more line to the original code, setting `geometry` property of `clonedProperties`.

My code (without any external library) is as follows:

```
const clonedFeature = feature.clone();
const clonedProperties = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(feature.getProperties()));
clonedProperties.geometry = clonedFeature.getGeometry(); // see EDIT
// Maybe do something with clonedProperties as I do.
clonedFeature.setProperties(clonedProperties, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem in ol@6.5.0. In my case, i used the `feature.clone` method to clone an animate feature, when i changed the clone feature's scale、opacity、rotation properties, the origin feature has changed too.

I go to the ol's github issues find no answers, i guess the `feature.clone` api has't deep clone the properties. So i read the ol's `feature.clone` source code, and find the feature'style does't clone, so just rewrite the clone api and clone the style will solved the problem.

```js
/**
   * Clone this feature. If the original feature has a geometry it
   * is also cloned. The feature id is not set in the clone.
   * @return {Feature} The clone.
   * @api
   */
  clone() {
    const clone = new Feature(
      this.hasProperties() ? this.getProperties() : null
    );
    clone.setGeometryName(this.getGeometryName());
    const geometry = this.getGeometry();
    if (geometry) {
      clone.setGeometry(geometry.clone());
    }
    const style = this.getStyle();
    if (style) {
      // clone.setStyle(style);
      // just setStyle the clone style
      clone.setStyle(style.clone());
      
    }
    return clone;
  }
```